# How to use database password?

Tags: php, passwords

I am very new to php. Currently I am working on a project, where data from a database server should be fetched and then returned to a client. I have got this little code snippet:

```
<?php
  $host_name = 'host';
  $database = 'db';
  $user_name = 'user';
  $password = 'passwd';
  $link = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

  if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('<p>Connection failed</p>');
  } else {
    echo '<p>Connection success.</p>';
  }
?>
```

The ugly part is, that the password is written in the source code. When using gitlab or something similar, the password is always uploaded - in each software version. This is (of course) a huge security risk. How can I make this more safe? Store the password in a file and read the file with php to get the database password - would that be a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you could use a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), but It would be a major change in your development.
What Laravel does is generate a `.env` file. This file contains all the app credentials (database, mail, etc.). You could do the same : make a file that won't be in your git (add it to your `.gitignore`) (a JSON file for example).
When you clone the repository, you will just have to create this file.

For example, a JSON file named `credentials.json` :

```
{
    "database": {
         "login": "your-login",
         "password": "your-secret-password"
     }
}
```

You can easily read a JSON file with PHP.

Clearly, you have to manage your `.htaccess` to make this file unreadable from the outside.

**Note :** you can add to your git repository a blank file to keep the JSON file structure, without the credentials in a `credentials-example.json` :

```
{
    "database": {
         "login": "",
         "password": ""
     }
}
```

After cloning, you will just have to rename the file and add the credentials.